# how to get an average image from multiple images in C#

Tags: image-processing, emgucv, opencv3.1

i want to create an average image from a set of multiple images (around 100) of same size in C#. Is it possible to do the same using EMGUCV, OPenCV or any other method without using any library. Please help me out or share the code if possible

Answer (score 0):

With OpenCV in C++, here is an [example](http://answers.opencv.org/question/42911/solved-how-to-average-n-matrices-into-1/):

```
Mat acc(img.size(), CV_64F, Scalar(0)); // all black, *double* image
accumulate(img1,acc);
accumulate(img2,acc);
accumulate(img3,acc);
accumulate(img4,acc);
//...
accumulate(img100,acc);
Mat avg; 
acc.convertTo(avg, CV_8U, 1.0/100); // back to u8 land, divide by count
```

It should be quite trivial to port it to C#.